# Data structure that stores strings and ignores letter case

Tags: java, string, data-structures, set

I know that `HashSet<String>` data structure can store unique strings and say if string is present with O(1) complexity, because it uses hash code. Can the same complexity be achieved, if I want to ignore letter case? Next use case should work:

```
Set<String> set = new IgnoreLetterCaseSet();
set.add("New York");
set.contains("new york") == true;
set.contains("NEW YORK") == true;

set.each(it -> print it) ---> prints "New York"
```

Is it possible to implement such data structure?

Comment: @dave last line of code - prints New York, as it was inserted, I can't normalize the string to lowercase on insertion

Comment: What if you created a new class that extended `String`, overriding the `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` methods?

Comment: @jameslarge String class is final, can't extend.

Comment: Oops!  That's a bummer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a HashMap with original string as value and lower case one for key

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.add("New York".toLowerCase() ,"New York");
map.containsKey("new york".toLowerCase()) == true;
map.containsKey("NEW YORK".toLowerCase()) == true;

map.values().each(it -> print it) ---> prints "New York"
```

Comment: so I have to wrap a HashMap to get O(1) I guess

Answer (score 6):

Maybe TreeSet is what are you looking for ?

```
TreeSet<String> ts=new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Comment: `SortedSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);` where `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` is a Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with `Java`, but here are two ideas on how you could do this:

1. Define a new comparer to use in the `HashSet` that ignores case.
2. Have the `HashSet` hold a list of `string`s that all have the same key. That is, `New York` and `NEW YORK` will both be in the list under the key `new york`.